# Run StyleCop for Unit Test Projects on build

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, stylecop

I prefer running StyleCop for most of my projects automatically on build, by adding `<Import Project="$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.Targets" />`
 to project's `*.csproj` file and also set to "All", "Treat warning as errors" property on a given project to break builds if is there an warning raised to fix those as early as I can.

Anyway, this works quite good for me, except for "Unit Test Projects", that for some reason, don't "trigger" StyleCop" on build event.

Any ideas please?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this could help you out: http://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/

Comment: @Matthijs if you'd put your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it. Thank you.